# why making a new variable result a different value here?

Tags: java

I have two sets of code. if I make  a new variable inside the loop, the code works as it's suppose to.

```
public static int subsequentLeapYear(int year) {
    for(int i =1; i < 9; i++) {
        int nextYear = year + i;
        if(isLeapYear(nextYear)) {
            return nextYear;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

public static int subsequentYear(int year) {
    for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        year += i;
        if(isLeapYear(year)) {
            return year;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
    System.out.println(subsequentYear(8));
    System.out.println(subsequentLeapYear(8));
```

it's suppose to print 12. for the first one it prints 36 not 12. I can't figure out why it's printint 36.

Edit:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        if(year % 400 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if(year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: you add i (not 1 to year). so you test 9 11 14 18 23 29 36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because:

```
int nextYear = year + i;
```

`year` is always the **same value**.

ex:

```
i=1 -> nextYear = 8 +1 = 9;
i=2 -> nextYear = 8 +2 = 10;
```

While:

```
year += i;
```

year is not always the same value.

```
i=1 -> year = 8 +1 = 9;
i=2 -> year = 9 +2 = 11;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reasone is here:

```
year += i;
```

You add every iterator value like 1,2,3,4 .. 9.

When `isLeapYear` gives true the i = 7 at the same time when is second case it's 4.

The point is that in `subsequentLeapYear()` each time you create new variable with value. And in the `subsequentYear` you're using the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is your code `year += i` is not producing what you are expecting.

Here’s what’s going on

```
year = 8; 
year += i; // i = 1, year = 9 now.
year += i; // i incremented up; is now 2. year = 11 now.
```

What should happen is you should replace `i` with 1 to prevent numbers from being skipped.